# Is there an opposite of tightfisted that also contains reference to a hand?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an opposite of tightfisted that also contains reference to a hand?

The opposite of 'tightfisted' is always 'generous'.

I want a word, idiom, or phrase that means generous but with reference to hand or a form or part of it like fist etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

openhanded (adj) - giving freely; generous.

Might be the closest you'll get.

Comment: Indeed; it's hard to get closer than a bulls-eye.

Comment: In my experience, *tightfisted* is almost exclusively used when referring to someone's willingness to give money, specifically. *Openhanded* is used mostly for money, but also hospitality and a general willingness to help.

Answer (score 2):

To give a hand. When you want to help or be generous to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Gladhand. While not an exact match, it's closely related. Typically used to describe one who is "working the crowd" with smiles and handshaking. Frequently used when the persons motives are political in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but *handy* conveys something of the desired intent.

And, more of a "neutro-nym" than an antonym, but there's also *even-handed*.